# Format to 2 decimal places for textview value from SQLite

Tags: android

I want to display the value from SQLite database into the textview. I want the value to be always 2 decimal places. I want to try to use DecimalFormat but not really sure on how to write it since I fetch the value from database.

Example : 13 will be 13.00 and 13.2 will be 13.20

```
package com.example.calculator;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Displaydata extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBManager dbManager;
    TextView display;

    DecimalFormat formater = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_displaydata);

        display = findViewById(R.id.display);

        dbManager = new DBManager(this);
        dbManager.open();
        Cursor cursor = dbManager.fetch();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        display.setText(cursor.getString(1));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format your String before setting it to the TextView:

```
display.setText(String.format("%.02f",cursor.getDouble(1)));
```

Comment: Hi. I tried but it says this java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String

Answer (score 0):

Try to format your value like this:

```
String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", cursor.getString(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your textview text as

```
display.setText(String.format("%.2f", (double)cursor.getString(1)));
```

Edit:
The second arguement expected is a float. So cast your string to a double value.

Comment: Hi. I get an error java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String